# Heroku - Getting a SQLite error even though it is not in the Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite, pg

I've removed the sqlite3 gem from my gemfile and replaced it with pg, deleted the gemfile.lock and re-bundled, and there are no dependencies in the new gemfile.lock which require sqlite3, so why am I still getting this error?

Comment: What is in your database.yml file?

Comment: Ah! Thanks. It's still saying sqlite3 in there for some reason.

Comment: add your gem file and some more information to your question so other person can help you out

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was that I had sqlite3 in comments within database.yml. After removing those comments, my project was able to get up and running again.